# VisualStateManager seems not to work with .NET 4.0 (wpf)

Tags: .net, wpf, visualstatemanager

I wanto to override the Default Button Style in order to have only an image button, without a border and all that stuff.

That's all working perfectly, but although I defined the VisualStateManager in my XAML Style, the button can't be pressed with the mouse. In fact, it does nothing.

What do I do wrong?

```
<!-- Button Style -->
<Style x:Key="WinImageButton" TargetType="Button">

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>

    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Setter.Value>    
    </Setter> 

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentControl x:Name="RootElement">
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                    </ContentPresenter>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="RootElement"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" 
                                                 To="2.0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="RootElement"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                                 To="-2.0"  />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                </ContentControl >
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by _the button can't be pressed with the mouse_? Is this a visual issue? Your expecting something else to happen at the point of clicking the Button but it is not?

Comment: The Style i posted above is a Button Style. Create a button and asign that style above. The Button will be displayed (without border and all stuff), but the click on that button will result in no action. But If you look at the VisualStateGroup it should be moved 2 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the TranslateTransition to inside the ControlTemplate itself?  (You can put it in the resources section of the template.)